# How to access JSON object with Jquery (WikiAPI)

Tags: jquery, json, wiki

I am getting the below json return from wiki:

```
{
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "1514": {
            "pageid": 1514,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "exampletitle",
            "extract": "Example extract"
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I access the "extract" value from this json? I will not know the page id (1514) and can't simply do a 
    json.query.pages.1514.extract;

(anyway .1514 will not work)

Thank you!

Comment: if you don't know page number, how do you suppose to get data in case there are 20 pages in `pages` object? Or you need ALL of them and looking for a way to iterate it as array?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the pages object to access its members

```
for(var key in json.query.pages){
    if(json.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(json.query.pages[key].extract);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.query.pages['1514'].extract` should work

Comment: Ah! However, I won't know that it's 1514 unless I can access the pageid

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse()

ex:

`var [your_parsed_JSON] = JSON.parse([your_JSON_variable])`

---

heres a similar stackoverflow question with more detail/examples:

[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

---

EDIT: actually it appears you are trying to access the contents of a container that you do not know. That's like trying to find the "lost treasure" without knowing where it is.

Reorganize your data structure.

Comment: It's the wikimedia API though, I don't have control over the data returned!